# ImGui::SetNextWindowSizeConstraints() not behaving as intended

Tags: c++, imgui

I'm trying to give my window a minimum size using `ImGui::SetNextWindowSizeConstraints` and putting it before the `Begin()` block as documented, like so:

```
void Widget::draw()
{
  ImGui::SetNextWindowSizeConstraints(ImVec2(500, 500), ImVec2(-1,-1));
  ImGui::SetNextWindowBgAlpha(m_opacity);
  
  if (ImGui::Begin("widget", true, ImGuiWindowFlags_NoScrollWithMouse | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoScrollbar | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoFocusOnAppearing))
  {
     //code for window here
  }
  ImGui::End();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to minimize my window, it still becomes smaller than the min_size of 500 pixels. Any idea why that might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this is because my windows were docked, and `SetNextWindowSizeConstraints` doesn't apply to docked windows. A workaround I've found is to use this code between the `Begin()` and `End()` blocks:

`ImGui::PushStyleVar(ImGuiStyleVar_WindowMinSize, ImVec2(500, 500));`